How to make Linux FIFO file with template content within?
I want to make a simple web server by using some linux commands like below. I created a fifo file.
$ mkfifo mkfifohtml.txt
Ncat listens at port 8080 then head and cut extracts simply the demanded file. After all, the file is being read and piped to mkfifotml.txt, which is input for listened port in Ncat.
I have the following code:
cat mkfifohtml.txt | ncat -k localhost -l 8080 | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f2 | sed -r \'s/\///g\'| xargs cat > mkfifohtml.txt

The requested file for example index.html has the content below:
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>

localhost:8080/index.html
When I give the address of web server (localhost), the browser says that there was an invalid response. I checked it out and found that the mkfifohtml.txt was a file without all the response codes and headers. I decided to make my own:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html


My question is the following:
How can I preset the mkfifohtml.txt with the response code and headers? Because, after using this fifo file it removes the content inside. How can I make a template fifo file like below?
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>

